# Releasing my application

Tags: android

I'm trying to release a signed APK for my app, but I'm receiving this kind of error. I changed proguard files to proguard-android-optimize.txt and set debuggable to false plus i changed the minifyEnabled to true.
Any Suggestions on how to solve this error ?

[Build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a04U2.png)

[Proguard-rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbkdd.png)

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MyWN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Update your minSdkVersion to 16